# Getting command terminated when trying to display element of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector, terminate

So I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to make this program. The point of the program is: you enter an array, and the program calculates which subarray has the largest sum that is a odd number and prints out how many elements the subarray has.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void swap(int *x,int *y){
    int temp=*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=temp;
}

void subarr(vector<int> arr,int start, int end){
    vector<int> a;
    vector<int> A;  
    int sum=0;
    if(end==arr.size())
        return;
    else if(start>end)
        subarr(arr,0, end+1);
    else{
        for(int i=start;i<end+1;i++){
            sum+=arr[i];
        }
        int num_of_elements=(end+1)-start;
        a.push_back(sum);
        A.push_back(num_of_elements);
        subarr(arr,start+1,end);
    }

    for(int j=100;j<a.size();j++){
        if(a.at(j)%2!=0){
            if(a.at(j)>a.at(0)){
                swap(&a.at(j),&a.at(0));
                swap(&A.at(j),&A.at(0));
            }
        }
        else{
            a.at(j)=-1;
        }
    }
    cout<<A.at(0);

    return;
}

int main(){
    int elements;
    cout<<"Enter number of elements: ";
    cin>>elements;

    int a[elements];

    cout<<"Enter "<<elements<<" elements in an array: ";
    for(int i=0;i<elements;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }

    vector<int> arr;
    for(int i=0;i<elements;i++){
        arr.push_back(a[i]);
    }
    
    subarr(arr,0,0);

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles without an error. I run it, it  let's me enter all the inputs, but then I get the following message:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)

Comment: `*x,*y;`   it should be `*x = *y;`  in swap function.

Comment: @Krishna Kanth Yenumula still not working, getting the same error

Comment: why do you put parameters Start and End ? while you can get it it from arr.size()

Comment: @JaziriRami it was just simpler for me, could that be what causes the error?

Comment: please do not fix the code in your question. Fixes are for answers. I rolled back your edit, because with the update half of the answer is meaningless

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 my bad, first time using this

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from this line:

```
cout<<A.at(0);
```

You have to be careful about accesing elements outside the given size of A. As you can only access the item at position `0` is there is one item in the vector.

See [terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217093/terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-stdout-of-range)

Also for this:

```
for(int j=100;j<a.size();j++){
    if(a.at(j)%2!=0){
```

Ensure that you really intend to access the 100th element of `a`.

To trace through the program:

- It begins with  `subarr(arr,0,0);` which then adds something to the `A` vector.
- Then `subarry(arr,1,0)` is called, which then calls `subarray(arr,1,1)`.
- `subarray(arr,1,1)` returns, jumping back to the function call of `subarray(arr,1,0)`
- And you are back to the function call which hasn't added anything to `a` or `A`, skipping the for loop and then goes to print `A.at(0)` which is invalid.

Comment: I changed to int j=0, that was obviously my mistake, but apparently I didn't put any elements inside of an array, even though I did using push_back

Comment: @bb_823 because `subarr(arr,0, end+1);` gets called with start `1` and end `0`, which then returns. So in the first if statement block, nothing gets added to A. Something does get added to A but in the previous stack, when you recursively call the function, A will be initialized to a new valuew.

Comment: so technically my code is fundamentally flawed, should i do something like: void subarr(vector<int> arr,int start, int end, vector<int> a,vector<int> A) instead of my current subarr function. I will declare vector<int> a and vector<int> A in my main function

Comment: @bb_823 I recommend that you avoid the use of recursion (calling the same function within itself), and make use of for loops to loop over different lengths of the array. And if you feel up to it, you could look into functions such as `accumulate` and iterators e.g. `int sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);`. Just take it slowly and learn as you go and then you can always open another question for another specific issue. Hope that helps