# Converting String to Hex Throws Error: 'std::out_of_range'

Tags: c++, integer, hex

I have a really simple program that converts a hex string to it's int value. The code seems fine, but it throws a runtime error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
> what():  stoi

Here is the code where the error is being caused:

```
int dump[4];
string hexCodes[4] = {"fffc0000", "ff0cd044", "ff0000fc", "ff000000"};
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    dump[i] = 0;
    dump[i] = stoi(hexCodes[i], 0, 16);
    cout << dump[i] << endl;
}
```

I have tried reading a couple of pages such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217093/terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-stdout-of-range). I still can't find anything that relates to my issue. What am I doing wrong that is causing this error?

Comment: `0xff000000` is 4278190080. The largest value that can be stored in a 32 bit integer is 2147483647. If you convert this value to hexadecimal the reason should become obvious.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik 32-bit hex values with the highest bit set correspond to negative integers. You should post an answer explaining why `stoi` doesn't convert a string beginning with `8` through `f` to a negative int.

Comment: @Spencer "*32-bit hex values with the highest bit set correspond to negative integers*" - only when the hex represents a *signed* integer.  It could represent an *unsigned* integer instead. The code in question *assumes* signed, but could be tweaked easily to support unsigned instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau stoi returns a signed integer, after all. Even if it could be tweaked, we don't know if OP is interested in signed or unsigned, in which case `stoul` should be used instead. So clarification from Packa, or at least an answer that covers both cases, is required for this question.

Comment: Packa: What output were you expecting to get?  `4294705152`, or `-262144`, or something else?

Comment: @NateEldredge 4294705152 was the expected result. All the other indexes are positive not negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stoi` will throw `out_of_range` if the value is not in the range that `int` can represent.  The number `0xfffc0000` (4294705152) is not in that range for a 32-bit `int` as it is greater than 2^31-1 (2147483647).  So throwing the exception is precisely what it must do.

`unsigned` would work, but there is no `stou`, so use `stoul`.  You then probably want to use `unsigned dump[4]` since you know the value can be represented by an `unsigned int`. (Again, as long as they are 32 bits on your system.  `uint32_t` might be safer.)   As a bonus, this will ensure that `cout << dump[i]` prints out `4294705152` as desired.

(If you switch to `stoul` but keep `dump` as an array of `int`, the value will be converted to `int` by the assignment.  Under C++20, and for most common systems under earlier C++ standards, the conversion will "wrap around" to `-262144`, and outputting `dump[i]` with `<<` will print it out just that way, as a signed integer with a minus sign.  So that doesn't seem to be what you want.)